# Help me understand VOOC fast charging for lithium-ion batteries

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I know common VOOC chargers have a fast charging rate of 18W (9 V, 2 A). But how is it possible when the current is only 2 A? I mean 2 A current only has a stored charge of 2000 mAh (2A*1h). How can changing the voltage charge the battery faster?

On the other side a Oneplus Dash charger supports upto 20 W (5 V, 4 A). It makes sense that a higher current can charge a battery faster. But again, how can just 5 V charge a battery at a 4 A rating?

Comment: what kind of a battery are you talking about? ... you should really include all information in your question.

Comment: Lithium ion batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Li-ion cell charging voltage ranges from ~3.7V to 4.2V. 18W/4.2V = 4.29A. The charger has a DC/DC voltage converter circuit which pulses current through an inductor to 'transform' the voltage down and current up. This process is typically 85~90% efficient, so it should be able to deliver 4A for most of the charge cycle.

> But again how can just 5V can charge battery to 4A rating?

20W/4.2V = 4.76A, or ~4A at 85% efficiency. The OPPO VOOC (Voltage Open Loop Multi-step Constant-Current Charging) 'Flash Charging' system claims to charge certain OPPO devices from 0 to 75% in 30 minutes, implying a capacity of ~2.7Ah.

At 4A a 4Ah cell would only get 50% charge in 30 minutes. Charging to 75% would take (4Ah x 75%) / 4A = 45 minutes.

At 75% charge the cell has probably reached 4.2V, then current must be reduced to avoid damaging the battery. Getting The last 25% into the cell may take another 20-30 minutes.

Comment: The/some fast chargers work by charging at cc > c until 4.3V is reached then terminating for a fixed period then repeating. When the charge time approaches zero they go to cv mode .